# getting element from array one by one and createbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UItextFeild as search bar on clicking a tableview with suggestion open.now i want to click on that row and make a button with its label in below view as described in image .how can i acheive this [image: here is how i want]

I want it one by one means when i click on row it create a button on view and UITableView hide then again i start searching and on again clicking on some other row make a button with different value of X.

```
 _selectednames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.sortedArray.count];


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
           // MGContactItemsModel *model = _arrayForContacts[indexPath.row];
    self.searchText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_sortedArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
self.tableView.hidden = YES;

[_selectednames addObject:_searchText.text];

for (int i; i < _selectednames.count ; i++) {
    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:i];

       }
```

now in my makeLabelsAndButtons funtion i done something like this

```
CGFloat xOffset = 10.0f;
int buttonCount = 0;

CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 10.0, 50.0, 15.0);

NSString *nameString = [self.selectednames objectAtIndex:indexPath];

     UIButton *_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   //_button.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 10.0, 50.0, 15.0);
   for(int i=buttonCount; i >0;i++) {

    xOffset = xOffset+10;


    buttonFrame.origin.x += buttonFrame.size.width+xOffset;





}
 _button.frame = buttonFrame;
   buttonCount++;


_button.tag = indexPath;



//button.center = CGPointMake(xOffset, 10.0f);
//[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:picString] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setTitle:self.selectednames[indexPath] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_button.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:8.0f];

    _button.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    _button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[self.buttonView addSubview:_button];
NSLog(@"name: %@", nameString);
```

also on clicking button it will removed.any help would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.Please try it.

```
 y=20;
 x=20;

            for (int i=0; i<[arrAssignUsers count]; i++) {
                CGRect screenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
                CGFloat screenWidth=screenRect.size.width;


                [arrBtnStatus addObject:[NSNumber  numberWithBool:NO]];

                NSString *strNames=[arrAssignUsers objectAtIndex:i];
                stringsize=[strNames sizeWithAttributes:
                            @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f]}];
                btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                CGFloat m=x+stringsize.width+10;
                CGFloat n=screenWidth-20;

                if (m<=n) {
                    btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y,stringsize.width,stringsize.height);
                    x=x+stringsize.width +10;
                }
                else
                {
                    y=y+stringsize.height+10;
                    x=20;
                    btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y,stringsize.width,stringsize.height);
                    x=x+stringsize.width+10;
                }

                [btn setTitle:self.arrAssignUsers[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                btn.tag=i;
                [btn addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(notifyButtonPressedInEditTask:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                btn.backgroundColor=WHITE_COLOR;
                btn.layer.cornerRadius=10;
                [btn.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
                btn.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
                btn.layer.borderColor=[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;

                [self checkNotifybtnStatus:btn];
                [cell addSubview:btn];
            }
        }
```

It may helps to you.Thank you

Comment: what is arrBtnstaus in this and also stringSize ,i mean why u have used this array..? can you explain

Comment: Please press the up  arrow

Comment: actually the button which we have created become again and again on every new creation of button ...what to do ..?

Comment: no of button == array count ?
If you want create multiple button on click of row every time ,then first remove all object from array then add

Comment: mean i dont understand .please explain buddy .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView to create buttons. All you need to do is
 1. Create custom cell with button as you want
 2. When you tap on table view cell, add item to array and reload UICollectionView
 3. Show buttons and it will automatically add scrollview for you.

When you tap on UICollectionView cell, remove object from array and reload UICollectionView again.
This will more easy as compared to adding buttons and setting frames.

And design UICollectionView cell in such way that it will same length as your text, use NSLayoutConstraints for it. It will work fast and smooth.
Code will be minimum and reusable.

Comment: can you provide me some code actually m new to ios development .thanks for help anyways.

Comment: I cant provide whole code, but I can surely provide you some reference links. And those are:
https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout

Using this you can create tableview cell with dynamic width and height as  per text.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this working code...
Take UIScrollView in your Xib for buttons

```
//Adding menu buttons
    btnArray = @[@"SYMPTOMATIC", @"SOCIAL", @"VOCATIONAL", @"PERSONAL"];
    [self addButtonsInScrollMenu:btnArray];


/**
 *  Add Menu Buttons in Menu Scroll View
 *
 *  @param buttonArray Array containing all menu button title
 */

#pragma mark - Add Menu Buttons in Menu Scroll View
-(void) addButtonsInScrollMenu:(NSArray *)buttonArray
{
    CGFloat buttonHeight = self.menuScrollView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat cWidth = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0 ; i<buttonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *tagTitle = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat buttonWidth = [self widthForMenuTitle:tagTitle buttonEdgeInsets:kDefaultEdgeInsets];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(cWidth, 0.0f, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        [button setTitle:tagTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:12.0f];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[button setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i;
        [self.menuScrollView addSubview:button];


        UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, button.frame.size.height - kButtonBorderHeight, button.frame.size.width, kButtonBorderHeight)];
        bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
        bottomView.tag = 1001;
        [button addSubview:bottomView];


        if (i == 0)
        {
            button.selected = YES;
            [bottomView setHidden:NO];
        }
        else
        {
            [bottomView setHidden:YES];
        }

        cWidth += buttonWidth;
    }

    NSLog(@"scroll menu width->%f",cWidth);
    self.menuScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cWidth, self.menuScrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: my array elements increase on clicking tableview row

Comment: just add new element in array on each button click and call 'addButtonsInScrollMenu' method.

Comment: in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

[btnArray addObject:@"row 5"];

Comment: And call    [self addButtonsInScrollMenu:btnArray];

Comment: Or you can just pass a single string instead of NSArray each time you select any table row.

Comment: but then how can i provide position to button .if there is only one element every time...?

Comment: Define cWidth as a global variable. That's it.